# Oracle Database 11g ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We are trying to enter 1.6M records in a table, however, we are running into the  "undo tablespace" error described below. Any suggestions? We looked at other similar errors here, but didn't find a solution.

Couple notes:

1. We just installed the db application today.
2. We entered 1.6M records in another table successfully. Didn't commit afterward.
3. Then, tried adding another 1.6M records into another table and got the error.
4. Tried committing the first 1.6M records, but still got the error.

Error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDOTBS1'
30036. 00000 -  "unable to extend segment by %s in undo tablespace '%s'"
*Cause:    the specified undo tablespace has no more space available.
*Action:   Add more space to the undo tablespace before retrying
           the operation. An alternative is to wait until active
           transactions to commit.
```

Comment: The UNDO tablespace is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Came across a YouTube video that had enough info to help me piece together the answer (I found the video only OK, but helpful):

https://youtu.be/CSD0JFc9mtw

Couple notes

1) First note that in order to release the space in the UNDO tablespace, you have to "commit" the transaction(s).
2) Second note the UNDO tablespace has a size limit.
3) Last, it also has a retention time, so even after you commit the transaction, you have to wait a defined time before it releases the space to be used.

The third was the part that tripped me up because I couldn't understand why even after commiting the transactions I still was having issue with the UNDO tablespace.

To fix the problem all I had to do was increase the size of the tablespace, then to avoid the problem next time,  I reduced the retention time (careful with the second part - see video).

Increase size with this:

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\MYDBLOCATION\UNDOTBS1.DBF' RESIZE 1024M;
```